# Loop won't search through entire array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

For javascript, I have an array of objects and I want to see if a user's entry matches 2 of the properties of any of the three objects in my array. For some reason my 'for loop' only works for the first object but never checks the other two. How can I fix this?

```js
class Customer {
  constructor(fN, lN, bal, cID, pass) {
    this.firstName = fN;
    this.lastName = lN;
    this.balance = bal;
    this.customerID = cID;
    this.password = pass;
  }
}

const bankers = [];
bankers.push(new Customer("Jack", "Scott", 3689.21, "4552", "2811"));
bankers.push(new Customer("John", "Smith", 2500.00, "4553", "1234"));
bankers.push(new Customer("Albert", "Price", 100000.00, "4554", "6189"));

let userID = prompt(`Please enter your customer ID.`);
let userPass = prompt(`Please enter your password.`);

for (let i = 0; i < bankers.length; i++) {
  if (bankers[i].customerID === userID && bankers[i].password === userPass) {
    console.log('Yay'); break;
  } else {
    console.log('boo'); break;
  }
}
```

My 'for loop' only works when I test for the first customer. If I try to enter a customerid or password for the other two it fails. Why is this happening? I thought the `i` variable should go through all 3 objects

Comment: @Ele That was a potentially harmful edit. You added a quote. Their description suggests that that shouldn't be a problem, but we don't know that for sure.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the adjusted code. It's able to find the second entry fine.

Comment: @WaliH: I was about to make the same edit, only without the missing quotation mark and point to it in a comment.

Comment: I've voted to close as a typo/non-reproducible for now, as the code, as posted in the question, works.

Comment: The typo was when I pasted my question here. I do have quotes in my existing code

Comment: @WaliH The code here works though. Try the "run snippet" and enter in the info. I got a `Yay` for the second customer.

Comment: @WaliH: Then is the "boo"-"Yay"-"boo" for input 4553/1234 correct?

Comment: No it fails when I enter 4553/1234 it says boo when it shouldnt

Comment: yeah 4553 sorry

Comment: When I enter that, I get `"boo"/"Yay"/"boo"`.  Is that not what you expect?

Comment: I only get yay when I enter the first persons id and password so 4552 and 2811. the other two are boo

Comment: I can't replicate that.  Does it happen in the snippet above?  For me, all three work properly, and mismatches return three "boos".

Comment: I just added a missing component to my code. the for loop is supposed to break after it finds the correct one. and when i implement the break, that's when it doesn't work.

Comment: There is only supposed to be one yay or boo

Comment: The please see the answer from @JackBashford, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Two things - one, you were missing a quote in front of `Jack`. Two, you need to redefine your variables each time your loop runs - move your `userID` and `userPass` declarations *inside* your loop:

```js
class Customer {
  constructor(fN, lN, bal, cID, pass) {
    this.firstName = fN;
    this.lastName = lN;
    this.balance = bal;
    this.customerID = cID;
    this.password = pass;
  }
}

const bankers = [];
bankers.push(new Customer("Jack", "Scott", 3689.21, "4552", "2811"));
bankers.push(new Customer("John", "Smith", 2500.00, "4553", "1234"));
bankers.push(new Customer("Albert", "Price", 100000.00, "4554", "6189"));

for (let i = 0; i < bankers.length; i++) {
  let userID = prompt(`Please enter your customer ID.`);
  let userPass = prompt(`Please enter your password.`);
  if (bankers[i].customerID === userID && bankers[i].password === userPass) {
    console.log('Yay');
  } else {
    console.log('boo');
  }
}
```

## EDIT

Based on the comments, I believe you want to use `some` like so instead:

```js
class Customer {
  constructor(fN, lN, bal, cID, pass) {
    this.firstName = fN;
    this.lastName = lN;
    this.balance = bal;
    this.customerID = cID;
    this.password = pass;
  }
}

const bankers = [];
bankers.push(new Customer("Jack", "Scott", 3689.21, "4552", "2811"));
bankers.push(new Customer("John", "Smith", 2500.00, "4553", "1234"));
bankers.push(new Customer("Albert", "Price", 100000.00, "4554", "6189"));

  let userID = prompt(`Please enter your customer ID.`);
  let userPass = prompt(`Please enter your password.`);
  if (bankers.some(banker => banker.customerID == userID && banker.password == userPass)) {
    console.log('Yay');
  } else {
    console.log('boo');
  }
```

Comment: I was under the impression that they wanted to enter a single time, and do a look up based on that, but the intent also isn't 100% clear.

Comment: Moving those inside would have different behavior.  As it is (with Ele's fixes), the code checks each banker against the data from the prompts.  I think that's what the OP wants.  If you move them inside, you prompt for each banker and ensure that it's in the nth position... slightly odd.

Comment: Yes it's just a single time entry

Comment: So @WaliH You want to check if *any* `banker` has the user ID and password, and log `yay` or `boo` on that Boolean?

Comment: Yes I just want the user's entries to be able to match the id and password of any of the three customers

Comment: That `some` is a useful extension of the code.  Perhaps even better would be `find`.  But I don't think any of this addresses the question, which was quite possibly just due to a typo.